# RecyclerView that does not scroll and shows all items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView (and some other views) in a ScrollView. Currently the RecyclerView is laid out as very small (it shows 2 items out of 5 that it contains) and it scrolls independently of the ScrollView, which is obviously not great UX. I would like to get the RecyclerView to not scroll and to extend so that all its items are visible.

(I know it's stupid to use a RecyclerView in this case. I'm only doing this because somewhere else in the app I need a normal RecyclerView with scrolling etc. but the same kind of content, and I don't want to duplicate code).

Comment: ScrollView isn't build for handling nested scroll. Have you checked `NestedScrollView`

Comment: Did you manage to show all items at once in a "NonScrollRecyclerView"? For some reason my recyclerview doesn't seem to recalculate its height after I add more than 3 items

Comment: Facing a similar issue. Did you figure a solution? @JeffersonTavares? I've using wrap_content and nested scrolling disabled.

Comment: You can set RecyclerView height manually.

Comment: Using a RecyclerView is not stupid this case, for the very reason you explained yourself amongst other ;-)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It’s pretty simple, simply set the `RecyclerView`’s height to `wrap_content`.

You might also benefit from disabling nested scrolling on the recycler view, like so:

```
RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: That's right. On a side note, I actually did have `RecyclerView`'s height set to `wrap_content`. The issue I was facing was connected with an awkward combination of fetching a view with Picasso's asynchronicity and views getting in/out of the visible area. And that's a topic for an entirely separate q/a.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you must use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView. I've written about it below.

Comment: Doing this approach are you not losing the recycler view in recycling the views and just making a big list with already all the views on it in a big scroll view? If you try to load a lot of items in that recycler view maybe you get "lagging".

Comment: @William yes, that’s the point with wrap_content on RecyclerView. It will bind all items. I personally consider this a bug - RecyclerView should recycle when the item is offscreen, not only when the item is off its bounds. But the bug I filed was ignored. So right now you should probably use wrap_content only for small datasets, or use a button to load more items.

Comment: @Natario Yeah, I've gotten this problem, to manage it I calculate the recyclerview height manually as the nestedscrollview is being scrolled. Don't getting any lagging in doing so, and is pretty fast.

Comment: @WilliamDaSilva Indeed, but given that they've deprecated ListView, etc. it's what you have to use.

Answer (score 37):

The solution of **setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)** isn't as full as it should: you need to use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollViewfocusableInTouchMode="true" to the child of the NestedScrollView .

If you insist on using ScrollView, you should also set minHeight to the RecyclerView, and also set overScrollMode="never" . In this case, it still isn't a good solution because the minHeight might not be enough in some cases

Other alternative solutions that you should consider:

1. Replace the ScrollView&RecyclerView with a single RecyclerView, which has views with additional view type for what you had in the ScrollView
2. Use GridLayout or another layout instead.

Comment: does using `recyclerView` inside `scrollView` affects performance ?

Comment: If you implement it well, it shouldn't.

Comment: @VadimKotov Docs related to what?

Comment: @androiddeveloper to this behaviour of NestedScrollView, RecyclerView

Comment: @VadimKotov Sorry this was a long time ago.

Answer (score 31):

Maybe it is not completely clear at first sight what to do with all these answers.
I just tried them and the working one is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/person_properties"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
...
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

No need to change anything programmatically.

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 13):

In your activity.xml file

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityName">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

     </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In RecyclerView use **android:nestedSrollingEnabled="false"** and use **NestedScrollView** as a parent Scroll View.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me - I had a ScrollView wrapping two RecyclerViews.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using RecyclerView inside ScrollView then Replace `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView` and enable the nested scrolling

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

This Solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is to use in your Custom Adapter, inside the `onBindViewHolder` method this line: `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`

Answer (score 3):

I realised that I use `BottomNavigationView` which blocked my recycler view from displaying the last item. I fixed it by adding `paddingBottom` to it:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recipient_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="70dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view"
                />
```

Answer (score 2):

Also try to play with:

```
android:overScrollMode
```

Comment: Agreed, `android:overScrollMode="never"` is a nice addition because it hides the over scroll scrims

Answer (score 2):

You should **replace** your **scrollView** for **androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView** with matchparent, its simple and work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code for disabling scroll in the recycler-view, and showing all the items in your layout. It might work:

```
public class NoScrollRecycler extends RecyclerView {

    public NoScrollRecycler(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public NoScrollRecycler(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NoScrollRecycler(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int style){
        super(context, attrs, style);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){

        //Ignore scroll events.
        if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            return true;

        //Dispatch event for non-scroll actions, namely clicks!
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

use like this way:

```
<com.example.custom.NoScrollRecycler
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_white"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had a recycler view inside a scrollview.

Using NestedScrollView, "height=wrap content" on recycler view, and "nestedScrollingEnabled=false" on recycler view worked.

However I had to go a step further since my recycler view data and height changed after layout:

```
recylerview.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(recylerview.width,View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)

val height = recylerview.measuredHeight
recylerview.layoutParams.height = height
```

Comment: Just to add you can put this in anytime after the recyclerview is attached -- no need to override the view class for onlayout or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

probably parent of recyclerView is a constraintLayout changed it to RelativeLayout